# NetworkManager doesn't trigger ethernet disconnection

Tags: networkmanager

**UPDATE:**

- NOT working ONLY on Raspberry Pi 3.
- working on Rasberry Pi 1 and Rasberry Pi 2.
- testing using the same exact SD card.

**UPDATE END**

I have a raspberry pi where I installed NetworkManager.

I wrote 2 keyfile, `wifi` and `ethernet` (both with permissions 600) and they work great:

- I can plug/unplug the **ethernet** cable and the disconnection/connection to the lan triggers correctly.
- Same thing for the **wifi**, I can start/stop the wifi router and the disconnection/connection to the wifi triggers correctly.

There is only one case where NetworkManager doesn't correctly behave:

- If the Raspberry is booted up **WITH** the ethernet cable connected and then after the boot I unplug the cable, the status of the ethernet connection remains connected and there is no way to make it change state.
- On the other hand if the Raspberry is booted up **WITHOUT** the ethernet cable connected and after the boot i plug it in/out repeatedly, the state of the connection follows accordingly.

`ethernet`

```
[connection]
id=ethernet
uuid=60d17e82-1be7-3d0f-b924-e980be41fcba
type=ethernet

[ipv6]
method=ignore

[ipv4]

# use this block to use dhcp wired connection
method=auto

# otherwise use this block to set the connection manually
# method=manual
# address1=10.0.0.123/16,10.0.0.1
# dns=10.0.0.1;8.8.8.8;
```

`wifi`

```
[connection]
id=wifi
uuid=319f2d8e-3ce7-4e47-b6eb-fabb0aa69f68
type=wifi

[wifi]
mode=infrastructure
ssid=Facco

[wifi-security]
auth-alg=open
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
psk=facco2016

[ipv6]
method=ignore

[ipv4]

# use this block to use dhcp wired connection
method=auto

# otherwise use this block to set the connection manually
# method=manual
# address1=10.0.0.123/16,10.0.0.1
# dns=10.0.0.1;8.8.8.8;
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out this was the issue.

There is an issue with the current version of the ethernet driver:

https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/1100